# django celery: Import error - no module named task

Tags: django, python-2.7, celery

I am a beginner in django celery so unaware of the deep concepts of the celery. I have installed all the required packages like celery, rabbitMQ and permissions as well. after goin through the documentation of celery i have wrriten my code but when i am firing the command 
 ./manage.py celery worker -c 2
I am getting-- 
 ImportError: No module named tasks.

all the changes in settings.py already done and in tasks.py i am importing--
from celery.task import task.
I am not able to overcome this error.
thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If you do `./manage.py startapp sitetasks` and put your tasks.py inside the new app-directory (/sitetask/) and then add sitetaks to you install_apps in settings.py.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing python-dev . This is a common error when python doesnt find the dependencies